# Oracle SQL update column with join

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have a table Officer, and populated some data in there. Then a new column called Total is added to that table. Now I need to populate this new column with some aggregation data that is selected from another table. How to achieve this without using PL/SQL?

The relationship between the two tables I am using

[image]

I want to initialize the column as the total number of times each police officer has booked a driver for a traffic offence. I tried the following approach but it doesn't work.

```
update officer q 
set q.TotalNumberOfBookedDrivers = a.total
left join (
    select officer_id, count(off_no) as total
    from offence
    group by officer_id
)a on q.officer_id = a.officer_id ;
```

Comment: Side notes: (1) When counting rows, use `count(*)`. `count(something)` in contrast indicates that this something can be null and you only want to count the non-null occurrences. (2) `TotalNumberOfBookedDrivers` is not a name I'd recommend. Names in the database ar case insensitive, so a tool or somebody may run a beautifier over your code and change the name to `totalnumberofbookeddrivers`. It is common to use underlines to make names readable in SQL: `total_number_of_booked_drivers`.

Comment: It is generally not recommended to store aggregates redundantly. You wouldn't store the total hence, because you can always get it from the offence table. If, howver, you know you will want  to remove old rows from the offence table and still keep the totals, then yes, store this total as you intend to do, because it is no longer redundant. In that case the officer table would have the real total, whereas the offence table would have it incomplete. You'd write a trigger to always update the officers' totals, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a join to update with data from another table. The straight-forward approach is an update with a correlated subquery:

```
update officer
set TotalNumberOfBookedDrivers = 
(
  select count(*)
  from offence 
  where offence.officer_id = officer.officer_id
);
```